# DisplayPort window rendering issue

Tags: display, displayport

I have a strange issue with some windows rendering on a Dell monitor with DisplayPort (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS). Often I see up to 13 lines where the pixels appear to be cyclically shifted (see image), so that the edge of the window is moved in from the left, with the pixels to the left of the window being taken from the right hand side - as you can see this can make lines of text difficult to read. If the window is constantly updated, such as with animations, the shifted lines jump around the display window. I have checked whether it is a hardware issue, by changing the cable, and the output ports on the PC, but this does not make any difference.

[image: Example of pixel-shifted window]

EDIT: it's not only google-chrome, though that is where the issue is most noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enquiring on the Google product forums - it appears that the problem has been solved by turning on hardware acceleration in

chrome://flags

Other programs where the issue occurs only use software rendering, and there's no option to change to hardware acceleration, so are effectively unsolvable.