# Some windows have rendering issues?

Tags: display, google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad 5i, and have recently been experiencing rendering issues with some applications and windows.

One of the most prominent apps that this happens to is Google Chrome, but I've seen it in other apps as well. For Chrome, it usually goes away on its own after about 10-15 seconds, but it can stay for the entire duration an application is open. For some other apps, it makes typing very slow as well.

Some affected apps I've noticed:

- Google Chrome
- Some apps that use web-login popups
- Obsidian MD

Apps not affected:

- Firefox
- VS Code (strangely, as it uses electron.js, which is built on Chrome)
- Files app
- Terminal

This hasn't been happening until a few weeks ago. I tried upgrading all of the packages on my system through `apt`, but to no avail.

[image: Vertical lines spanning the entire window]

Does anybody have any recommendations on how I could diagnose the issue? I have taken a look at [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886070/displayport-window-rendering-issue), but it didn't help.